# Text lost when TextView display long text without space

Tags: android, textview

My `TextView` and all of its containers was set `layout_height` to `wrap_content`. It displays text with space in it (eg: English) well but with text without any space (eg: Japanese or just some long text without space in it), `some text was lost.`

It seems to work correctly when i append that `text without space` with two spaces and a letter. Omg i don't know why :(

```
msg += "  a";
```

Below is my layout. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/push_header_bg" >      
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/push_logo" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"            
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/push_center_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_push_sub_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/push_sub_header"
        android:textSize="20dp"        
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"         
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />     
        <TextView            
            android:id="@+id/tv_push"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:textSize="20dp"             
            android:text="今日は、何事にもパワフルなエネルギーに満ちている1日。また..."            
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"             
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />       
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"         
    android:gravity="center"       
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/push_footer_bg" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="@string/push_btn_close"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_open"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="@string/push_btn_open_app"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this thing by localization

1. create a folder values-ja in res folder of your project
   make strings.xml and put your Japanese string here

**res>values-ja>strings.xml**

```
<string name="TextValue">今日は、何事にもパワフルなエネルギーに満ちている1日。また...</string>
```

use this "TextValue" in your layout.xml file. Like:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/TextValue" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

Comment: Thank you. But that string is just an example, the Text string will be  set programmatically in java code.

Comment: Which API you are using for this app?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether my output is correct or not coz i don't know Japanese ,,, but i use Japanese data in UTF8 form and it display like this (screen shot is given bellow) [image]

in this i perform append and space.